Proper morphism
Maybe this could be a silly question, but I am considering the following problem.
Let $G$ be a connected reductive group and $X$ be an affine $G$-variety, i.e., $G$ acts on $X$. (You can assume the smoothness of $X$ if necessary.) Furthermore, let us assume that the centre $Z(G)$ of $G$ acts trivial on $X$, i.e., $z.x=x$ for all $z\in Z(G)$.
Then we can consider the following stable locus subset $Y:= \{ x\in X| x\ \text{is stable} \}$. Here, $x$ is stable means that the stabiliser $G_x/Z(G)$ is finite and $G.x$ is closed.
Then is the canonical map $f: Y/\!/G \rightarrow X/\!/G$ proper?
I appreciate any comments in advance.

Could you explain what are $X//G$ and $Y//G$?

Ah I am sorry for that. I am considering the GIT quotients (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIT_quotient) X//G and Y//G.

Your subset $Y$ could be empty, for example, if $G$ is non-trivial adjoint and acts trivially.  I think that $Y$ is also a priori just a subset, not a subscheme, so I'm not sure how to make sense of the GIT quotient.

@LSpice Thank you for your comment. I missed the point that Y could not be a subscheme. Then how about replacing Y as a set of stable locus of X? I.e., Y is the set of elements x in X such that G_x/Z(G) is finite and G.x is closed. Then Y//G -> X//G is proper? Or can we say something about this map? (I hope this question makes sense, but please let me know this question is not meaningful to think. By the way, I am also curious this question when we consider the semistable locus, but the stable locus case would be very helpful to me.)

Re, the question now makes sense to me, though I don't know the answer. And of course there's nothing inconsistent in the claim that $Y$ is open when it's empty; somehow I read your claim as being that $Y$ is open and dense.  Sorry about that!

This is false. Let $G = \mathrm{GL}_2$ and $X$ be the vector space of binary quartic forms $q \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, with action given by linearly substituting and dividing by the square of the determinant $g\cdot q = q((x,y)\cdot g)/\det(g)^2$. The determinant factor ensures that the center acts trivially.
The ring of $G$-invariant polynomials is generated by two invariants $I$ and $J$, so $X//G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^2$. On the other hand, the stable locus $Y\subset X$ equals the subset of quartics $q$ that are products of four distinct linear factors. The discriminant $\Delta$ of $q$ is a certain linear combination of $I^3$ and $J^2$, and has the property that $\Delta(q) \neq 0$ if and only if $q$ is stable. Therefore $Y//G$ is the subset of $X//G = \mathbb{A}^2$ where $\Delta$ (seen as a polynomial in $I,J$) does not vanish. This is an open and dense subset of an affine space, so the inclusion is not proper.
The following paper summarizes the invariant theory of binary quartics:
Bhargava, Manjul; Shankar, Arul, Binary quartic forms having bounded invariants, and the boundedness of the average rank of elliptic curves, Ann. Math. (2) 181, No. 1, 191-242 (2015). ZBL1307.11071.

Thank you for your answer! This looks very good, and this will be very helpful to me.
